# Can a uniform circular motion be considered as simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

The acceleration in a circular motion is directed towards the centre and is directly proportional to the radius of circle if it has uniform angular velocity. Is circular motion with uniform angular velocity simple harmonic motion?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: This should be an answer, IMO.

Comment: @user36790 posted it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is circular motion with uniform angular velocity simple harmonic
>   motion?

No. Simple harmonic motion is the 2-D projection of uniform circular motion on a plane.

Comment: +1; Probably, OP is meddling periodic motion with simple harmonic motion. Though every SHM is periodic, every periodic motion is not SHM.

Comment: I don't think the answer is a straightforward no. The two are closely related and you can think about uniform circular motion as a two-dimensional SHO. SHO is one-dimensional, btw.